# yii2:data of related model in Gridview

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have two models namely MedicineRequestEntry and MedicineRequest. MedicineRequestEntry is related to MedicineRequest via

```
public function getMedicineRequests()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MedicineRequest::className(), 
['medicine_request_entry_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

Now in grid-view of MedicineReuestEntry I am trying to pull the data from MedicineRequest Model using the relation using two alternative ways

like

```
[
           'attribute' => 'is_delivered',
            'value'=> 'medicineRequests.is_delivered'
        ],
```

In this method I am getting the value as not set.
and another method:

```
[
               'attribute' => 'is_delivered',
               'value'=> '$data->medicineRequests->is_delivered'
            ],
```

In this method I am getting the error like:

**Getting unknown property: app\models\MedicineRequestEntry::$data->medicineRequests->is_delivered**

Now I need some help, what I am doing wrong here.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a callback function, see [the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#grid-columns):

```
[
    'value' => function ($data) {
        $str = '';
        foreach($data->medicineRequests as $request) {
            $str .= $request->is_delivered.',';
        }
        return $str;
    },
],
```

Or for the first result of the array:

```
[
    'value' => function ($data) {
        return $data->medicineRequests[0]->is_delivered;
    },
],
```

Comment: Hi @deacs - Thanks. But I am still getting the error like `Trying to get property of non-object` and the line `return $data->medicineRequests->is_delivered;` is being highlighted

Comment: Ah, you have a `hasMany` relation, so you get an array of MedicineRequests back. You cannot use `$data->medicineRequests->is_delivered` or `medicineRequests.is_delivered` because `medicineRequests` is an array. Try my edit, and remove `medicineRequests.is_delivered`

Comment: Thanks @deacs. It is now returning the data, but the problem is still not resolved How can do this. for example `is_delivered` is repeated` over multiple rows and I want the grid-view rows to be repeated as many times for all the results. is that not possible?

Comment: Ah Yes comma separated results will do, but for your first example also I am getting only the first result with just a comma ,

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed the first example.

Comment: Also, it is possible to get a row in the gridview for each entry of the relation too. For that you will have to edit the `search()` method in your `MedicineRequestEntrySearch` class to `JOIN` your tables, but that is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Hi Deacs can you suggest how I can get separate row as that will serve my purpose better.

Comment: Please give sample for get grid-view rows to be repeated as many times for all the results.

Comment: @sasi for that you would have to look into eager loading http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#lazy-loading-and-eager-loading